# Did IKAROS wake up from its 5th hibernation in Winter 2015?

Tags: probe, interplanetary, solar-sail, deep-space-hibernation

The [IKAROS solar sail](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IKAROS) entered its fifth hibernation in spring 2015, with a planned wake up in winter 2015 (Northern Hemisphere). However, there seems to be no news since then regarding the mission status.

Is there any information on if the probe successfully woke up as expected?

Comment: In the Northern Hemisphere, there is winter in both January and December. Do you mean the beginning of 2016, or the end (hemisphere-agnostic)?

Comment: @uhoh it was actually planned to be in the second winter of 2015, after going into hibernation during spring 2015.

Answer (score 2):

According to JAXA, the fifth wakeup was expected in the winter of 2015, not 2016.
http://global.jaxa.jp/projects/sat/ikaros/topics.html#topics4743

Comment: Good catch - edited the OP, this is what I get for not checking Wikipedia's sources (and only skimming the JAXA mission page). Unfortunately, that doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: That link is the JAXA home page for Ikaros. If there's no news on that page, it's unlikely to be anywhere else. A quick search for Ikaros news articles hasn't turned up anything more recent.

Comment: I couldn't find anything else either. On that same website, however, it does indicate that the craft is still [in operation](http://global.jaxa.jp/projects/sat/ikaros/index.html). So I'm assuming it woke up? Either that or they didn't update their website, or expect to be able to wake it up in the future.